# Can't link with libcurl - undefined references to multiple functions

Tags: c++, gcc, curl, g++

I am currently having Problems compiling a C++ Program on Windows 7 x64.

It fails to compile in every way I try to:

```
undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
undefined reference to `curl_easy_perform'
undefined reference to `curl_easy_strerror'
undefined reference to `curl_easy_cleanup'
```

The Code itself:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://steamcommunity.com");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    if(res != CURLE_OK)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}
else
{
}
return 0;
}
```

I am compiling with:

```
g++ -DCURL_STATICLIB -g -o curlprogram curlprogram.cpp -LJ:\Projektpath -lcurl
```

I've added the libcurl.a in the Path specified by -L and also put libcurl.dll into C:\Windows\System32.

Answer (score 1):

*.a is not used for windows binaries, put libcurl_imp.lib into your -L path and use -lcurl_imp . Try link shared library without -DCURL_STATICLIB

Comment: If I try the .dll I get the following Error:
libcurl.dll: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Same when I remove -DCURL_STATICLIB

Comment: sorry, my mistake, in windows you work with *.lib. I changed the post. -lcurl_imp

Answer (score 0):

First  go to Properties > Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories > Include directories. Here, add the curl directory to be found in the include directory of the unzipped Libcurl file (C:\ … \libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc\include\curl).

Go to VC++ Directories > Library directories. Add the Debug directory containing curllib_static.lib, curllib.dll and curllib.lib (C:\Users\Édouard\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\LibCurl\lib\Debug).

Still in Configuration Properties, go to Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies. Here, you have to add the curllib.lib file (C:\  … \lib\Debug\curllib.lib). Type in up to name of the lib file.

The next step consists on adding curllib.dll, libeay32.dll, openldap.dll, and ssleay32.dll in the Debug directory of your project. There all are to be found in the root  directory of Libcurl.